# without using sleep how can i give delay in python

Tags: python, delay

Without using `sleep` function from `time` package how can I give delay in python?

I am getting this error when I'm using `time.sleep(10)` function:

> FATAL error: Read register at (0x00100020)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the delay function from pygame module

```py
import pygame 

pygame.time.delay(1000)
# equivalient to time.sleep(1)
```

But the real solution is to fix the problem with the sleep function.
Dit try something like this ?

```sh
pip uninstall time
pip install time
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try and let you know.

Comment: I tried unistalling time using these commands pip uninstall time but it didn't work for python 2.7.8. How to uninstall time package ??

Comment: You should follow the instruction that I found here https://michigantechit.teamdynamix.com/TDClient/KB/ArticleDet?ID=66715

Comment: The error is : Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping.

Answer (score 0):

**time.sleep(**)  is not working because of output buffering.

Turn it Off then it will work. Same problem was with me and it worked for me.

For turn off output buffering, you can follow this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/107717/3184637)